# Facebook Graph Api - leadgen_form endpoint (v12) not filtering

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to filter the response from the leadgen_form endpoint but it is giving me the message:

```
(#100) Filtering field 'leads_count' with operation 'greater_than' is not supported
```

The request I am  making is:

```
/v12.0/{page-id}/leadgen_forms?fields=id,created_time,name,status,leads_count,expired_leads_count&filtering=[{'field':'leads_count','operator':'GREATER_THAN','value':0}]
```

Is it really not possible to filter on this simple integer property or am I doing something wrong?

Second question I have, is the leadgen_forms endpoint still supported? On a topic on the Facebook Developers portal it is mentioned to be deprecated since V5.0(?). But the endpoint is still there in V12.0. See https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/630926654372206/?join_id=f3d05695fb730c